# Reading text line by line from SD

Tags: programming, esp32

Why does the following code return this error?  How can I make this work?

> Error: exit status 1 invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'
>   [-fpermissive]

```
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "SPI.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!SD.begin(33)) {
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Card Mount Succeeded");
  }

  File offline = SD.open("/offlineLog.txt", FILE_READ);

  while (offline.available()) {
    String line = offline.readStringUntil("\n");
    Serial.println(line);
  }
}
```

The docs say that stream.readStringUntil returns a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with what `readStringUntil` returns. It has to do with what parameters it accepts.

The function expects a *single character* to look for. Instead you are passing it a string (C string) containing one character.

In C you represent a string (`char *`) using `""`, and a single character (`char`) using `''`.

Since `readStringUntil` expects a `char`, not a `char *`, you need to use `''`:

```
String line = offline.readStringUntil('\n');
```

Comment: Thank you!  I wish that error message was more descriptive.